# How are these flywheel-like devices used in the Boeing 737 Max?

Tags: flight-controls, boeing-737, cockpit, feature-identification

The recent news video [CNN's exclusive look inside a Boeing 737 Max simulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPJls-fMQYs) shows a 737 Max simulator cockpit. There are a pair of what look like large black flywheels on the console, shown spinning on their own, and then coming to rest.

What do these do, how are they used, and why is such a large, apparently very haptic device felt to provide the pilot with the best information and/or interaction?

In the real plane (not this simulator) do these connect by cables directly to moving surfaces, or are they actuated only in order to provide information in the cockpit?

[image: CNN's exclusive look inside a Boeing 737 Max simulator]

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/31913/62), maybe a dupe?

Comment: what these do: [What are the advantages of a Trimmable Horizontal Stabilizer?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24934/14213)

Comment: I've closed my question as a duplicate. Normally I'd keep the question here to help point readers to the duplicate answer. But if the drive-by down votes continue I'll delete instead.

Comment: I'd leave the question here exactly as a pointer. The more paths we have to get people to a useful answer the better.

Comment: I know, I was just encouraging you to leave it here, despite any downvotes :-)